# ¿Cómo agregar una clase a un div usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Necesito agregar el siguiente atributo de bootstrap (col-md-6) a un div que por defecto se imprime ya con una clase existente:

```
<div class="images" style="opacity: 1;">
```

Ustedes dirán que lo haga directamente pero es una plantilla PHP que aún no la encuentro y me he cansado de buscarla entre el paquete. Por lo tanto pretendo que quede de la siguiente manera por medio de una secuencia JavaScript.

```
<div class="col-md-6 images" style="opacity: 1;">
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tener en cuenta que lo que tienes es una `clase` y no un `id` para que identifique a tu elemento, retornará un arreglo al hacer  `getElementsByClassName` por eso el uso del `for`.

- Con JavaScript puro (Sin Librerías, ni frameworks) mediante [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) esta propiedad retornará una cadena  con las clases del elemento seleccionado, para añadir una determinada clase a un elemento puede añadir el nombre de la clase para esto podría emplear la sintaxis básica de concatenación de cadenas **+=** , *(deberá tener en cuenta que hace falta un espacio adicional si no las clases terminaría juntas)* .

  ```
  var elemento = document.getElementsByClassName("images");
  for(var i = 0; i < elemento.length; i++)
      elemento[i].className += " col-md-6";
  ```

Sí su elemento tuviese un identificador `(id)` sería de forma directa

```
    var elemento = document.getElementById("images");
    elemento.className += " col-md-6";
```

- Por medio de Jquery , usaría [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) para añadir el nombre de una clase a un determinado elemento del HTML

  ```
  $('.images').addClass('col-md-6');
  ```
- También puede añadir clases utilizando la propiedad [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), esta propiedad contiene los siguientes métodos *más importantes*.

  1. Agregar una clase o más de 1 clase

     ```
     myElemento.classList.add('nombreclase');
     myElemento.classList.add('nombreclase1','nombreclase2');
     ```
  2. Eliminar una clase o más de 1 clase

     ```
     myElemento.classList.remove('nombreclase');
     myElemento.classList.remove('nombreclase1','nombreclase2');
     ```
  3. Verificar si un elemento contiene una clase

     ```
     myElemento.classList.contains('nombreclase');
     ```

Comment: El aporte ha sido muy bueno me ha funcionado. Ahora lo implementaré.

Comment: @Dev. Joel, excelente respuesta, me funciona!

Answer (score 5):

Para el manejo de clases de un elemento en javascript, te recomiendo utilizar el objeto `classList` el cual proporciona métodos para agregar, eliminar y verificar si un elemento está presente en la lista de clases.

**Version jQuery**

```
const $el = $('.selector');
$selector.hasClass('someClass');
$selector.addClass('newClass');
$selector.removeClass('otherClass');
```

**Versión sin jQuery**

```
const el = document.querySelector('.selector');
el.classList.contains('someClass');
el.classList.add('newClass');
el.classList.remove('otherClass');
```

Te recomiendo siempre tratar de escribir código sin jQuery.

Adjunto una referencia a `classList` para que puedas ver más en detalle su comportamiento.

> Referencia: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con que se deba evitar jQuery, es una librería muy completa y sinceramente me parece muy útil.

Comment: Nadie discute que no sea una librería útil, pero creo que hacerte dependiente de un framework o librería no es una buena práctica, siendo que existen maneras igual o más eficientes de hacerlas usando vanilla js. :)

Comment: dependencia de frameworks? Métete en la página que sea y verás que no solo usan uno si no varios, yo no digo que no se pueda hacer solo con JS, pero **evitar una librería que te simplifica el trabajo.....**. Cuando hagas un proyecto a lo grande te darás cuenta de que no es tan mala práctica como te crees.....

Answer (score 3):

### Solución para navegadores modernos.

Es posible hacer lo mismo que la respuesta de @Dev. Joel, pero utilizando [**classList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

A diferencia de `className`, en este método no es necesario concatenar las clases existentes con la que deseas agregar.

Se utiliza así:

```
var elemento = document.querySelectorAll(".images");
for (var i = 0; i < elemento.length; i++) {
  elemento[i].classList.add("clase-agregada");
}
```

Asimismo utilizamos [**querySelectorAll()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), pero bien puedes seguir utilizando `getElementsByClassName` para obtener una lista de nodos.

---

### FRAGMENTO DE CÓDIGO:

```js
var elemento = document.querySelectorAll(".images");
for (var i = 0; i < elemento.length; i++) {
  elemento[i].classList.add("clase-agregada");
}
```

```css
.images {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
.clase-agregada {
  border: 3px solid chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<div class="images" style="opacity: 1;">
```

---

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/bgwsnmg5/)**

---

Si deseas agregar más de una clase utilizando este método tienes que separar cada una por commas.

```js
var elemento = document.querySelectorAll(".images");
for (var i = 0; i < elemento.length; i++) {
  elemento[i].classList.add("clase-uno", "clase-dos", "clase-tres");
}
```

```css
.images {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
.clase-uno {
  border: 3px solid chartreuse;
}
.clase-dos {
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.clase-tres {
  outline: 3px solid dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="images" style="opacity: 1;">
```

---

Puedes checar los navegadores que soportan este método [**aquí**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist).

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad de los objetos *HTML* que definen la clase, es `className`, es tipo *string*.

Se puede modificar directamente, para **añadir** otra clase, simplemente añade el texto usando `obj.className+=" nombre";` (Deja un espacio antes igual que lo harías en *HTML*).

Código de ejemplo:

```js
caja.className+=" rojo";
```

```css
#caja {position:fixed;width:100px;height:100px;}
.rojo { background-color:red;}
.borde {border: 3px solid black;}
```

```html
<div id="caja" class="borde"></div>
```