# Agregar clases diferentes a un listado de DIV

Tags: javascript

Tengo un admin que agrega noticias dinamicamente a una pagina. Tengo dos clases diferentes diferentes que le da estilos distintos a las noticias. Desde el admin no puedo agregar esas clases. Como hago con javascript para que cuando el do que tengo armado las cargue desde mi admin le agregue por ejemplo a la noticia uno una clase y a la dos y tres otra y a la cuatro la misma que la uno?

Por ejemplo que quede asi

```
<div class="clase-1">
    <h2>Titulo</h2>
    <p>Bajada</p>
</div>

<div class="clase-2">
    <h2>Titulo</h2>
    <p>Bajada</p>
</div>

<div class="clase-2">
    <h2>Titulo</h2>
    <p>Bajada</p>
</div>

<div class="clase-1">
    <h2>Titulo</h2>
    <p>Bajada</p>
</div>
```

---

Los divs estan en un contenedor, y se que clases ponerle porque las tengo predefinidas. Lo que me importa es que la el primer div de noticias y el 4 tengan la misma clase.

Comment: Disculpa, que quiere decir esto, *que cuando el* ***do***?

Comment: intenta probar con algunos tag html. Ejemplo, en tu admin cuando escribas la noticia colocar el titulo así <h1>titulo</h1> y ve como queda la noticia.

Comment: Aqui te dejo una pregunta que hizo alguien mas, esta respondida y seguro te servira, [agregar css uando javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28007/c%C3%B3mo-agregar-una-clase-a-un-div-usando-javascript)

Comment: Esos `divs` que nos muestras de noticias están contenidos en algún contenedor exclusivo para ellas?

Comment: @Jonatan edité tu pregunta con lo que habías publicado como **respuesta**. Por favor consideralo para futuras aclaraciones.

Answer (score 1):

En el caso particular de agregar un elemento u otro, se puede hacer un bucle (loop) con una condición de si el iterador cumple con la condición, agregar una clase, en caso contrario agregar la otra. Ejemplo:

```js
/**
 * Actualiza la sección de noticias, al elemento non se le asigna
 * clase-1 y al elemento par se le asigna clase-2.
 *
 */
function cargarNoticias(){
  //Inicializar variables
  var noticias = '';
  var limite = 4; // Para efectos del ejemplo seleccionado arbitrariamente.
  var clase = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= limite; i++){
    // Si el iterador es uno o un múltiplo de 4, asigna una clase, en caso contrario la otra
    clase = (i == 1 || i%4 == 0) ? '"clase-1"' : '"clase-2"';
    //Cadena de noticias en formato HTML
    noticias += 
    '<div class=' + clase + '>\n' +
    '   <h2>Titulo</h2>\n'+
    '   <p>Bajada</p>\n'+
    '</div>'
  }
  //Actualizar la sección noticias
  document.getElementById('noticias').innerHTML = noticias;
}
```

```css
.clase-1 {
 color:red
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Cargar noticias" onclick="cargarNoticias()" >
<br/>
<div id="noticias">Sin noticias<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Los divs están en un contenedor ? ¿como sabes que clase añadir a cada div? Yo creo que necesitas traerte del admin(por ejemplo con ajax) las clases que le vas a dar a cada noticia, así podrás recorrer los divs y añadirles la clase apropiada.

Supongamos que tienes un array con las clases de cada noticia y tienes 4 noticias:

```
clasesNoticias=[
"clase-1",
"clase-2",
"clase-2",
"clase-1"
];
```

Ahora imaginemos que tienes un contenedor de noticias con las 4 noticias a las que quieres añadir la clase:

```
<div id="contenedorNoticias">
<div>
    <h2>Titulo</h2>
    <p>Bajada</p>
</div>

<div>
    <h2>Titulo</h2>
    <p>Bajada</p>
</div>

<div>
    <h2>Titulo</h2>
    <p>Bajada</p>
</div>

<div>
    <h2>Titulo</h2>
    <p>Bajada</p>
</div>
</div>
```

con estos datos, puedes recorrer los divs del contenedor de noticias y mirando en el array la case de cada noticia añadirle la clase al div.

```
let claseNoticia;
$( "#contenedorNoticias div" ).each(function( index ) { 

        claseNoticia = clasesNoticias[index];
        $( this ).addClass( claseNoticia ); 
});
```

Un saludo

Comment: Esto tiene múltiples problemas de ejecución. Sólo aporta una solución en el caso de ejemplo que nos ha proporcionado pero falla estrepitosamente  si hay 5 divs por ejemplo. Por no mencionar de que no todos los divs que vaya a haber en el HTML van a ser de noticias. Considero que hay aclaraciones que realizar antes de aventurarse a responder!

Comment: No puedo imaginarme su programa, con esa información que nos da es la solución para ese ejemplo. si quiere algo mas genérico que proporciona mas información. Saludos!

Comment: Aunque tienes razón en que efectivamente no puedes imaginarte su programa, disponemos de comentarios para solicitar más información si se considera necesario. Nuestro objetivo aquí es ayudar y proporcionar una solución a un problema. No obstante, igual es sólo percepción mía. Sería posible que para evitar confusiones añadieses unos comentarios en la respuesta para aclarar el alcance y contexto de la solución? De este modo evitamos confusiones al OP y a futuros usuarios que consulten esta pregunta.

Comment: De acuerdo, puede que tengas  razón, la verdad lo hice con buena intención al leer su pregunta yo creo que esta bastante clara, quiere añadir unas clases a una serie de divs, pero no dice nada mas por eso e pensado que el contexto no le importa y he ido a la practica, lo siento.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, no puedo hacerle comentarios hasta que no tenga 50 puntos, por eso le he respondido, un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido ioniJS. Veo que esta es tu primera publicación en [es.so]. Te comparto que es válido realizar respuestas parciales, ya sea porque la información es insuficiente, o porque deseas enfocar tu respuesta a algún aspecto. En lo personal considero que es mejor evitar el incluir preguntas incluso preguntas retóricas en las respuestas ya que tengo la impresión de que no son bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Otra observación es que aparentemente estas usando [tag:jquery], pero no lo has mencionado y más importante aún el OP tampoco. Considerando que hay una etiqueta específica para ese framework, cuando no se mencione es mejor proponer soluciones sin que lo requieren y en caso de ser "indispensable" explicar por qué se recomienda.

Comment: Vale Rueben gracias!! tendré en cuenta tus comentarios para la siguiente,  ¿Existe algún manual de uso? Un saludo.