# Como cambiar el valor apareciendo en filas sin borrar el contenido anterior en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una serie de botones con una clase llamada `botonesSistema`

Quisiera que al ejecutar una funcion cualquiera estos cambiaran su clase a otra llamada `EstadoSistemaEncendido`.

Probe de la siguiente manera:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("botonesSistema");
    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
        elements[i].className = "estadoSistemaEncendido";
    }
```

Ocurre que solo cambia la clase de los botones en posiciones impares, hay 10 botones y solo los botoens: `1, 3, 5, 7, 9` se ponen verdes (efecto de la clase).

Seguido sale este error en consola:

```
Cannot set property 'className' of undefined
```

Y al pulsar de nuevo se cambia la clase de los otros.

Con lo anterior los botones manejarían dos eventos, cambiar de color al ser pulsados y ademas decir el nombre de su id:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("botonesSistema");

    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
     elements[i].classList.add("estadoSistemaEncendido");
      elements[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
        this.classList.toggle(".estadoSistemaApagado");
    });
    } 

    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
        elements[i].onclick = function() {
            var id = this.id.replace("es", "");
            var mayus = id.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
            var resto = id.slice(1);
            var completo = mayus + resto;
            var mensaje = "[Sistema: " + completo + "]";
            alert(mensaje);
        }
    }
```

Añado el CSS usado y los botones HTML:

```
.botonesSistema{
}

.botonesAparato{
}

.estadoSistemaApagado {
    background-color: #f44336;

}

.estadoSistemaEncendido {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="1Accion" class="botonesSistema">
<input type="button" id="2OtraAccion" class="botonesSistema">
```

Comment: `elements[i].className += " estadoSistemaEncendido";` note el espacio al inicio del nombre de la clase.

Comment: debes eliminar el punto en la clase `.toggle(".estadoSistemaApagado");` debe quedar: `.toggle("estadoSistemaApagado");`

Comment: @fwBasic es algo parecido a un interruptor OFF/ON

Comment: @Victor-Random qué es lo que desea como resultado final ?

Comment: @Dev.Joel listo lo solucione jejeje, habia colocado un punto en clase y aparte habia colocado mal una letra de la clase :) corregido

Comment: ya haz publicado todo el código, lo que te falta es que sea funcional, hazlo y así podremos ayudarte con un ejemplo comprobable.

Comment: @fwBasic ya funciono *listo lo solucione jejeje, habia colocado un punto en clase y aparte habia colocado mal una letra de la clase :) corregido* gracias :)

Comment: @fwBasic eres de Venezuela :O ?, invitame a un chat , lei algo de tu pagina y quiero decirte algo :)

Comment: buscare a ver como se hace, soy nuevo aquí :))...

Comment: @fwBasic ya te invite a uno :), yo tambien soy de Venezuela

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una opción para manipular las clases de un elemento es recurrir a la propiedad [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) para *agregar*, *eliminar* , *toggle* y verificar si un elemento contiene una clase determinada.

```
elemento.classList.remove("miclase"); /* Eliminar*/
elemento.classList.add("miclase"); /* Agregar*/
elemento.classList.toggle("miclase"); /* Toggle*/
elemento.classList.contains("miclase") /* Verificar si contiene la clase*/
```

Para su ejemplo sería .

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("botonesSistema");
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
     elements[i].classList.add("estadoSistemaEncendido");
      elements[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
        this.classList.toggle("otraclase");
    });
}
```

```css
.estadoSistemaEncendido{
    background: red;
}
.otraclase{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="botonesSistema">
<input type="button" class="botonesSistema">
<input type="button"  class="botonesSistema">
<input type="button"  class="botonesSistema">
```

> También puede verificar esta  [Respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28007/c%C3%B3mo-agregar-una-clase-a-un-div-usando-javascript/28008#28008)

Comment: se te chispotearon los primeros dos comentarios verdad?

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo la verdad sí  xD.

Comment: @Dev.Joel publicare para que veas lo que tengo /funcionando mi anterior pregunta y esta/

Comment: @Victor-Random Cada pregunta se centra en algo en especifico , si se solucionó el problema se marca la respuesta y si presenta fallas posteriores debería crear una nueva pregunta si no la respuesta dada pierde credibilidad, además como consejo añada a sus preguntas el HTML ;)

Comment: @Dev.Joel automaticamente al usar la funcion se ponen en verde todos los botones pero luego al darles click no pasan a verde :)

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar el método `querySelectorAll()` usado en anteriores preguntas junto con el método `toggle()` de la propiedad `classList`. Con esto puedes crear una función que al pulsar uno de los botones obtengas un efecto donde cambie el color del botón, por ejemplo: **de rojo a verde y viceversa**.

Ejemplo:

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".botonesSistema");
el.forEach(function(e){
 e.onclick = function(){
  this.classList.toggle("Encendido");
 };
});
```

```css
.botonesSistema {
 color:red;
}
.botonesSistema.Encendido {
 color:green;
}
```

```html
<button class="botonesSistema">boton 1</button>
<button class="botonesSistema">boton 2</button>
<button class="botonesSistema">boton 3</button>
<button class="botonesSistema">boton 4</button>
```

Comment: Publicare como tengo mi codigo porque no cambia el color